# Translucent Theme Activity issue with rendering Images

Tags: android

I am using a Translucent AppCompatActivity, and in the layout of that activity I am trying to use an ImageView. I am putting the src of the image by using the srcCompat tag. I do the see the image on the design view of the Xml file, but not able to see that being rendered on the phone screen.
Thanking in advanced.

Comment: Use "AppCompatImageView" in place of "ImageView".

Comment: @TakeInfo...Thanks a lot. That solved the problem. Using AppCompatImageView it is now rendering

Answer (score 0):

First try using the **Layout Inspector** tool to verify that your ImageView has at least its width and height well defined. Go to Android Studio->Tools->Layout Inspector and analyze your layout.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` inside your Gradle file if it not there. Browse to this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources you can find more data here. If it is not resolved by adding this, you can use `android:src` attribute instead of srcCompact